# Парсинг Json, почему не работает?

Tags: java, android, json

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
    super.onPostExecute(strJson);
    // выводим целиком полученную json-строку
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, strJson);

    JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;
    String temps = "";

    try {
        dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);
        JSONArray opa = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("opa");

        JSONObject secondFriend = opa.getJSONObject(0);
        temps = secondFriend.getString("temps");
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Второе имя: " + temps);

        for (int i = 0; i < opa.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject friendsJSONObject = opa.getJSONObject(i);

            JSONObject temp = friendsJSONObject.getJSONObject("temp");

            String TempeOut = temp.getString("HumOut");

            String HumOut = temp.getString("TempeOut");
            tempInHouse.setText(TempeOut);

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "HumOut: " + TempeOut);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "TempeOut: " + HumOut);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Что я сделал не так?

Структура : JSON

```
temp
HumOut : "10"
TempeOut : "21"
```

StrJson содержит всю строку - {"temp":{"HumOut":"10","TempeOut":"21"}}

Нужно вывести в лог или на экран значение HumOut и TempeOut.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос стек ошибки, содержимое `strJson` и что должно было получиться

Comment: Добавил информацию с низу.

Comment: `JSONArray opa = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("opa");` ваш json не содержит array с таким названием

Comment: `// выводим целиком полученную json-строку
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, strJson);`

В логах показывает целиком?